# Extension of weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, a suppose that $\{y_n\}\subset L^1$ converges to $0$ with respect to the weak topology $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$. Now, suppose that there is $x\in L^1$ such that $x y_n\in L^1$ too. Is it true that $\lim E[x y_n]=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No:
Take $\Omega=(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure. 
$$
y_n(t) = n^{1/2} \chi_{[0,1/n]}(t)
$$
and
$$
x(t) = t^{-3/4}.
$$
Then it holds
$$
\int_0^{1} xy_n \ d\mu=  n^{1/2}\int_0^{1/n} x \ d\mu = n^{1/2} n^{-1/4}\to\infty.
$$
Here we have $y_n\to 0$ in $L^1$, $x\in L^1$, but $xy_n\in L^1$ is unbounded.